# How to add text box for entering a value to Slack chat bot as interactive user menu?

Tags: python, bots, slack

1) I want to add a text box so i can enter a value instead selecting predefined 
   values from dropdown

Below is partial code snippet for image for user interactive messages , what is the code to add text box to insert a value

````
 web_client.chat_postMessage(
        channel=channel_id,
        text=f"```Hi <@{user}>!```\n" + mgs,
        thread_ts=thread_ts,
        attachments =   

{

                "text": "I can create the following orders.",
                "fallback": "If you could read this message, you'd be choosing something fun to do right now.",
                "color": "#3AA3E3",
                "attachment_type": "default",
                "callback_id": "game_selection",
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "name": "games_list",
                        "text": "Choose fullfilment",
                        "type": "select",
                        "options": [
                            {
                                "text": "a) spu - store pickup",
                                "value": "spu"
                            },
                            {
                                "text": "b) sth - ship to home",
                                "value": "sth"
                            },
                            {
                                "text": "c) del - delivery",
                                "value": "del"
                            },
                            {
                                "text": "d) digitalAsGuest - Digital item",
                                "value": "digitalAsGuest"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]


}
        ]
}
````

Below is the image , where i was able to add dropdown menu and button menu but i need text box field

[image]

how to integrate below code for text field to **web_client.chat_postMessage**

```
{
    "type": "modal",
    "title": {
        "type": "plain_text",
        "text": "My App"    
    },
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "input",
            "element": {
                "type": "plain_text_input",
                "action_id": "sl_input",
                "placeholder": {
                    "type": "plain_text",
                    "text": "Please enter sku numberhere"
                }
            },
            "label": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "Sku number"
            },
            "hint": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "Example: 5580358"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: For an interactive text input field you need to use [Modals](https://api.slack.com/surfaces/modals)

Comment: Hi @ErikKalkoken can you please add the code?

Comment: No my friend. Stack Overflow is not a coding service, but aims to help people learn to code themselves. I pointed you in the right direction and I'd be happy to help you again if you get stuck with implementing it.

Comment: Thanks for adding your code. However, you still have quite a way to go. Modals are their own thing and not part of a standard message. You need to call [views.open](https://api.slack.com/methods/views.open) to create one and you need a `trigger_id` which you get from an slash request or interactive message. Check out [this documentation](https://api.slack.com/surfaces/modals/using) on how to use and implement models.

Comment: Slack documentation made me cry acid tears, we just drop the idea of having a nice text input on our bot message. You can use a simple slash command instead of a modal (that was our best option)

Comment: Very True Slack documentation was so confusing , felt like I was seeing similar content on multiple pages and btw thanks for above info.

Comment: What's the point of input boxes, select fields and buttons in a message block if you can't get a user's response? Seems strange.